# Use external libraries inside the build.sbt file

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it somehow possible to use an external library inside the `build.sbt` file?

E.g. I want to write something like this:

```
import scala.io.Source
import io.circe._ // not possible

version := myTask

lazy val myTask: String = {
  val filename = "version.txt"
  Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.mkString(", ")
  // do some json parsing using the circe library
  // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the things I actually like about sbt is that the build project is (in most ways) just another project (which is also potentially configured by a meta-build project configured by a meta-meta-build project, etc.). This means you can just drop the following line into a `project/build.sbt` file:

```
libraryDependencies += "io.circe" %% "circe-jawn" % "0.11.1"
```

You could also add this to `plugins.sbt` if you wanted, or any other `.sbt` file in the `projects` directory, since the filenames (excluding the extension) have no meaning beyond human convention, but I'd suggest following convention and going with `build.sbt`.

Note though that sbt implicitly imports `sbt.io` in `.sbt` files, so the circe import in your `build.sbt` (at the root level—i.e. the build config, not the build build config) will need to look like this:

```
import _root_.io.circe.jawn.decode

scalaVersion := decode[String]("\"2.12.8\"").right.get
```

(For anyone who hasn't seen it before, the `_root_` here just means "start the package hierarchy here instead of assuming `io` is the imported one".)